# How to dynamically update a rectangle's gradient?

Tags: qt, qml

I have this:

```
    Rectangle{
    id:testrect

    property color gradcolor:"#8C8F8C"
    gradient:
        Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: gradcolor }
        GradientStop { position: 0.17; color: "#6A6D6A" }
        GradientStop { position: 0.77; color: gradcolor }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#6A6D6A" }
        }
```

In a child MouseArea, I want to do this:

```
         onEntered: {
            testrect.gradcolor="white"
            parent.border.color = Qt.lighter("#6A6D6A")
```

The border color is changing as desired, but the gradient colors are not. Is it because the gradient is not pulling from the gradcolor property in real time? What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue seems to be that your `Gradient` element is not linked to `gradcolor` if you don't indicate which element contains the property. This works for me:

```
Rectangle{
    id:testrect
    width: 200
    height: 200
    property color gradcolor: "green"
    gradient: Gradient {
        GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: testrect.gradcolor }
        GradientStop { position: 0.17; color: "#6A6D6A" }
        GradientStop { position: 0.77; color: testrect.gradcolor }
        GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#6A6D6A" }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill:parent
        hoverEnabled: true  // Mandatory for hover events to work
        onEntered: {
            testrect.gradcolor = "red";
        }
        onExited: {
            testrect.gradcolor = "blue";
        }
    }
}
```

More information on QML scope can be found [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtqml/qtqml-documents-scope.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found this answer while looking for using canvas and gradients in QML

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Canvas {
    id:canvas
    property var ctx
    onPaint:{
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(0, 1, 1, 1);
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.beginPath();
        var radgrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(75,50,5,90,60,100);
        radgrad.addColorStop(0, '#A7D3FC');
        radgrad.addColorStop(0.5, '#019F62');
        radgrad.addColorStop(0.9, 'rgba(1,159,98,0)');
        ctx.arc(100,75,50,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = radgrad;
        ctx.fill(0,10,10,10);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    width: 360
    height: 360

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var p = ctx.getImageData(mouseX, mouseY, 1, 1);
            var red = p.data[0];
            var green = p.data[1];
            var blue = p.data[2];
            var alpha = p.data[3];
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure it could be relevent here, But just as an information i thought i can put it here, This worked for me
Thanks